# How to exit out of for loop with non zero status code?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have below shell script and I am trying to exit out of for loop with non zero status code but somehow my exit line doesn't work and it prints `Hello World` after it but I don't want it to print. What wrong I am doing?

```
  for env in dev stage; do
    echo "$env"
    false && echo howdy! || (echo hello && exit 1);
    echo "Hello World"
  done
```

For above case, it should print `hello` and exit out of it but it also prints `Hello World`

**Update**

If I try this then I get a syntax error:

```
for env in dev stage; do
  echo "$env"
  false && echo howdy! || { echo hello && exit 1 };
  echo "Hello World"
done
```

Error is:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `done'
```

I am running Python 2.7 version.

Comment: `(...)` creates a subshell. You want `{ ...; }` for grouping.

Comment: @BenjaminW. You're right. Deleting my post.  Not sure how that qualifies as "equal precedence" since it seems to give higher precedence to `||`, but ok.

Answer (score 2):

`(...)` introduces a subshell. `exit` exits the subshell, not the shell that runs the loop. Use `{ echo hello && exit 1 ; }` instead, `{ ...; }` stays in the same shell.

Comment: After changing that I get syntax error. I updated my question with details. What wrong I am doing?

Comment: You need the semicolon *inside* `{ ... ; }`

Comment: You changed the order of `; }`.